# Is it possible to see the source code responsible for high CPU in Windows Performance Analyzer?

Tags: performance-testing

When I run Windows Performance Analyzer with the ETL file collected during high CPU utilization periods, it displays the graphs where I can zoom into the spikes and see what processes consumed CPU cycles.

But what I really need is to see the actual function calls in the source code of those processes.

Is it possible to do that in WPA?

An example screenshot just for giggles (Trusted Installer is not my actual target)

[image]